# Bootstrap Sub Menu Slide Down

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to build a Wordpress template heres the site: http://ideedev.co.uk/flowmech/

I'm using much of the standard bootstrap nav, just with some style changes. The sub menu drops and appears instantly, but I'd like it to slide out. Query might be a bit too far for me so I've been looking at a fade out CSS option.

Here's my current CSS for the nav...

```
/* subnav */

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .sub-menu {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background: #222;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        width: 200px;       
    }

    li:hover .sub-menu {
        display: block;
    }

}

.sub-menu li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sub-menu a  {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu a:hover  {
    color: #fff;    
}   

.sub-menu {
    background-color: #2194ec;
    z-index: 20;
}

.sub-menu li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.sub-menu a  {
    color: #c5e4fc;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu a:hover  {
    color: #fff;    
}   

.current-menu-item > a, .current-menu-parent > a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00468A;
}

.current-menu-parent .current-menu-item a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

And here's the code I tried to add to make the menu:

```
.sub-menu ul {
    opacity: 0; 
    top: 30px; 
    visibility: hiden; 
}

.sub-menu ul:hover {
    opacity: 1; 
    top: 60px; 
    visibility: visible; 
    transition: all .25s ease; 
}
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect, where ever I put it...

If there is an easy Jquery solutions, I wouldn't mind giving it a go...

Comment: Would be great if you could post a jsfiddle so we could help you with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this one of two ways. You can use Jquery .slidedown which would help you accomplish this. You can read more about how to use and example at http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, but there are two things to mention here:

- The possible value for `visibility` is `hidden` (not "*hiden*")
- Your selector is not correct: `.sub-menu ul:hover` would work for a list element that is a child-element of `.sub-menu`. But actually you want to do something with `.sub-menu` when hovering it's parent `li`-element.

Use these as possible CSS selectors:

```
.nav.navbar-nav > li .sub-menu {}    
.nav.navbar-nav > li:hover .sub-menu {}
```

**Note**

When you set `transition: all .25s ease;` only for the `:hover` the menu will be hidden without animation. If you set it in the first selector, it will also move and fade when leaving the element.

Comment: Thank you so much for this - I have replied as an answer as it wouldn't let me post much text in this comment - hope that's ok.